# What could be causing my locally running IIS website to take so long to connect to SQL Server?

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, sql-server-2005

I am running a local web server for doing development. Right now the website connects to a local SQL Server running on my machine which is obviously fast. When I instead point the web app to connect to our DEV SQL Server it takes a really, really long time to connect. I can't figure out what it could possibly be doing that takes so long as when I connect to the same SQL Server through a local copy of my SQL Server Management Studio it connects and works really fast. What would cause my local web server to be so crazy slow connecting to the non-local SQL Server? Is there any sort of log or diagnostic I can run to determine this?

Answer (score 0):

What connection methods are enabled on the remote SQL server? What method is the web server using to connect to the remote SQL server? What protocols and name resolution methods are in use on your network; TCP, DNS, etc?

Comment: The connection string is in a web.config file and the ASP.NET MVC runtime makes a request to the SQL Server. It works fine for the web app communicating to the server where both are hosted in a data center but my local web app connecting to the SQL Server the same exact way is really slow. The only difference I know of is it is hosted on Windows Server 2003 and I am on Windows 7.